# How do I get a div to change the max-height upon window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

code: http://jsfiddle.net/MDnrk/7/

for those too lazy to click the link:

```
$j(function(){
    // need to fix some things that CSS doesn't seem to be able to fix (esp cross browser)
    fix_drawer_height()
    $j(window).resize(function() {
        fix_drawer_height()
    });
})


function fix_drawer_height(){
    var new_height = document.body.offsetHeight - $j(".redline_info_scrollable").offset().top; 
    $j(".redline_info_scrollable").css({
        'max-height': new_height + 'px;'
    });
}
```

now, in my app, fix_drawer_height() gets called on DOM ready, but it doesn't seem to be called in teh JS fiddle.. so I'm not sure if that is the correct medium to show this problem.

Still not sure what would couse the window resize listener to not set the max-height appropriately. =\

The goal is to have the scrollable div always stretch to the height of the window.

Normally I'd just use height: 100% in the CSS, but that isn't really cross browser, and won't work with how the div is positioned in my actual app.

thanks!

Comment: How is `height: 100%` not cross browser?  I think using a common CSS attribute would be much easier and more reliable than trying to re-implement the same browser functionality in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
function fix_drawer_height() {
    $('.redline_info_scrollable').height($(document).height());
}
```

and add it in your onload or onresize;

working code: http://jsfiddle.net/MDnrk/13/

Comment: nope, the resize part doesn't work. when the window gets small enough, a scrollbar should appear on the blak div.

Comment: Check out my linked modification of your fiddle, should be what you are after